# How to remove an element from a list while adding it to another list in Java?

Tags: java, list

I have two lists of type `List<Integer[]>`: `A.Unassigned` and `A.Shanghai`.

I tried the following:

```
Iterator<Integer[]> UnassignedIt = A.Unassigned.iterator();
A.Shanghai.add(UnassignedIt.next());
UnassignedIt.remove();
```

but it gives a `NoSuchElementException`:

> java.util.NoSuchElementException at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)

[How can I solve this?]

Comment: In Java variable names start with a lower letter or an underscore.

Comment: Can you post full stack trace.. From that exception, it is sure that you are not getting any element from your iterator..

Comment: `A.Unassigned` does not have any items in it

Comment: @Keyser - What if `A` is a class and `Unassigned` a static member

Comment: @techfoobar or even worse, `Unassigned` coudl be a public attributed from `A` class!

Comment: If it's a static class member and immutable it should be named entirely in capital letters. Once it is mutable it should follow the attribute naming convention. This looks more like an inner public class.

Comment: check if UnassignedIt.hasNext(); returns true; If false, you know why you get your exception.

Comment: @techfoobar Yes that's a possibility. I chose to think that he's simply doing it wrong since the rest of the example has specific names (`A` isn't) and the example would have been fine without the class reference.

Comment: @Keyser - OK. The reason I mentioned it is, had he used it as a variable name, it wont compile and the OP wouldn't have reached the exception he mentioned in the question.

Comment: @techfoobar That's a good point though. The only scenario that's left after that is the one where OP's don't post original code :p

Comment: @Keyser - That unfortunately happens a lot! :-)

Comment: Just started using java a week ago. Forgive me for the naming convention.
@Christain Unassigned is not empty. Checked.

Comment: @ChristiaandeJong Thanks! Found my mistake. `while(UnassignedIt.hasNext()){
unassignedPot += UnassignedIt.next()[1];}` before reassignment took the iterator to last element in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the iterator has a next item before calling `next()`:

```
Iterator<Integer[]> it = A.Unassigned.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Integer intArray = it.next();
    A.Shanghai.add(intArray);
    it.remove();
}
```

Also, [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html) might help a lot. And take the comments into account, the naming conventions, et cetera.

Answer (score 3):

Check this code :

> List listA = new ArrayList();
>           listA.add(1);
>           listA.add(2);
>           listA.add(3);

```
    List<Integer> listB = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    Iterator<Integer> iterator = listA.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        Integer obj = iterator.next();
        listB.add(obj);
        iterator.remove();
    }
```

the `java.util.NoSuchElementException` will happen if the list you are trying to access (using `iterator.next()` ) is empty. So better check if the `iterator.hasNext()` before doing that.